# Showing inequality $\tan{A}\tan{B}\tan{C}\ge 8$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, triangles, geometric-inequalities

> In acute  $\Delta ABC$ if$$\sin{A}=2\sin{B}\sin{C}$$
>   show that$$\tan{A}\tan{B}\tan{C}\ge 8$$

Here is a solution

since
$$\sin{A}=\sin{(B+C)}=\sin{B}\cos{C}+\sin{C}\cos{B}=2\sin{B}\sin{C}$$$$\Longrightarrow \tan{B}+\tan{C}=2\tan{B}\tan{C}$$
so
$$x=\tan{A}\tan{B}\tan{C}=\tan{A}+\tan{B}+\tan{C}\ge \tan{A}+2\tan{B}\tan{C}\ge 2\sqrt{2x}
$$$$\Longrightarrow x\ge 8$$

Is there any other method? Especially I would like to see a geometric solution.

Comment: I'm not sure how you get $\tan A+2\tan B\tan C\ge 2\sqrt{2x}$

Comment: use AM-GM inequality and  $x=\tan{A}\tan{B}\tan{C}$

Comment: Oh, yes, of course.